# Editing an alarm using AlarmManager

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I'm trying to make a simple homework reminder app I set an alarm with this function:

```
void setAlarm(int year, int month, int day, int hour, int minute, int second, String lesson, String description, int id)
{
    Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, MyReceiver.class);
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day);
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, second);
    intent1.putExtra("LESSON", lesson);
    intent1.putExtra("DESC", description);
    intent1.putExtra("ID", id);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, id, intent1, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
}
```

people say if you want to edit, you need to have the exact same pendingIntent so I did, but it doesn't seems to be working.

When I set an alarm and edit it WITHOUT it going off first, the alarm seems to cancel itself.

I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: To update a PendingIntent, it needs to have the same ID as the old with with flag PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT

Comment: @elmorabea yes I know but still it doesn't properly work